# Nginx config: two applications under same domain

Tags: nginx, virtualhost

I have two applications: HTML+JS frontend and PHP backend. I would like to set Nginx up so that both are served from the same domain. Requests to the backend are made uing URLs starting with `/api`.

My attempt was this:

```
server {
    root /path/to/frontend;
    index index.html;
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /api {
        alias /path/to/backend;
        index index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

However, for all requests to the backend, I end up with a 404: primary script unknown.

Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do here? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made the usual mistake of people not really understand how nginx works. Remember the following:

**nginx always serves a request with a *single* `location` block only**.

I suggest you (re)read the following: [How nginx processes a request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html)

Now, looking at your configuration, backend requests would need to be served by 2 locations:

1. `location /api`
2. `location ~\.php$`

Following [`location`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) documentation, the first on is called a *prefix* location, while the second one is a *regular expression* (regex) one. nginx will check both but will eventually only select one, which in your case is the regex one.

Now, when processing it, nginx will forward a request for `/path/to/frontend/<yourFile>.php` to PHP, building the path from `root /path/to/frontend`, since it is the only one defined. The backend then fails, unable to find the specified file.

You might wish to try the following:

```
location /api {
    alias /path/to/backend;
    index index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;

        # Useless? Request always ending up with '.php' here...
        fastcgi_index index.php;

        include fastcgi_params;

        # Try to secure this block, which might lead to arbitrary code execution.
    }
}
```

As for the lack of security, I hosted a talk about nginx and PHP-FPM at nginx.conf 2014 end October. Slides are available: https://rosset.net/LAMP_just_died.pptx. Video soon available.